# How to count the time interval, watch duration and sum of users watching the same live broadcast repeatedly?

Tags: sql, mysql

I am a newcomer to sql language. I have such a task now: I have a mysql table that records some information when users watch live broadcasts. The more important fields are as follows: user id, user_id; live broadcast id, account_id; the time when the user enters the live broadcast room, enter_time; the time when the user leaves the live broadcast room, leave_time; and the length of time the user stays in the live broadcast room, stay_time. Note that users may watch the same live stream multiple times, and there are more than one users.

The example of this table is as follows:

| user_id | account_id | enter_time | leave_time | stay_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 07:01:01 | 07:01:10 | 9.0 |
| 1 | a | 07:01:15 | 07:01:21 | 6.0 |
| 1 | a | 07:01:30 | 07:01:33 | 3.0 |
| 1 | b | 07:40:09 | 07:43:21 | 192.0 |
| 1 | b | 07:21:15 | 07:21:18 | 3.0 |

Now I have such a task to complete. It needs to generate a new sql table. This sql table records some behaviors of the user repeatedly watching the live broadcast: the user id, which is user_id; the most number of times the user enters the live broadcast room, recorded as most_retargeting_count; The room id, recorded as most_retargeting_account_id; the average entry interval of the live broadcast room that the user repeatedly entered, recorded as avg_most_enter_retargeting_gap; the average viewing time of the live broadcast room that the user entered the most, recorded as avg_most_watching_time.
For the above table, the output should be:

| user_id | most_retargeting_count | most_retargeting_account_id | avg_most_enter_retargeting_gap | avg_most_watching_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | a | 7.0 | 6.0 |

I've tried the sql statements below, but they are unmistakably wrong, and I can hardly go on. How can I accomplish this task?

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE t_new
SELECT 
t_cnt.most_retargeting_account_count most_retargeting_account_count,
t_cnt.most_retargeting_account_id most_retargeting_account_id,
t_avg.avg_watching_time avg_watching_time,
t_avg.avg_retargeting_time_time



FROM  (
    (select 
        t_pv.account_id as most_retargeting_account_id, count(t_pv.account_id) as most_retargeting_account_count
        from t_pv
        group by user_id
        order by count(t_pv.account_id) desc
    ) t_cnt 
    right join(
        (select 
            t_pv.user_id as user_id,
            avg(t_pv.stay_time) as avg_watching_time, avg(datediff(lead(t_pv.enter_local_time, 1), t_pv.leave_local_time, 'ss')) as avg_retargeting_time
        from t_pv
        group by user_id
        ) t_avg
    )
    on t_cnt.user_id=t_avg.user_id
)
```

Comment: `INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE tablename` is not MySQL syntax. The syntax is `INSERT INTO tablename`

Comment: What's wrong with your query (other than the syntax error above)? Can you post sample data, the desired result, and what you're getting instead? See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support for formatting tables in markdown.

Comment: @Barmar I have updated the question. In fact, I'm kind of at a loss as to how to write this logic; I've tried what the code in the text is about, but it looks like they're simply wrong

Comment: Your first subquery doesn't select `user_id`, so you can't use that in the join.

Comment: Why do you need two subqueries with a join? They're both grouped by the same column, so do all the aggregation in one query.